# Inserting a dash between two vowels in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to insert a dash between two vowels if my string has two consecutive vowels, I have an error as it is returning null.

```js
function insertDash(word) {
  const strWord = word.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < strWord.length; i += 1) {
    if (strWord[i - 1].includes(/[aeiou]/gi) && strWord[1].includes(/[aeiou]/gi)) {
      strWord.push('-');
    }
  }
  return strWord.join('');
}

insertDash("Thiis is a teest");
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `strWord[i - 1]` will return `undefined` when `i == 0`; also, the dash is being inserted at the end of the string, instead of the correct place.

Comment: `strWord[i - 1]` will be `strWord[-1]` on the first loop iteration and since there is no item at that index, it will be undefined. And, you can't call `includes` on `undefined`, hence your error.

Comment: Also, string `.includes` doesn't accept instances of regex

Comment: Apart from the indexing error(start with i=1 instead of i=0), you cannot use regular expression in `includes()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of problems with your code as described in the comments, but I would just try a simpler method. Do something like this, which will work without needing to iterate through the characters of a string which is causing most of your issues right now:

```
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    str = str.replace(/([aeiou])([aeiou])/g, '$1-$2')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```js
function insertDash(word) {
  const wordArr = word.split('');
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  return wordArr.reduce((sentence, letter, index) => {
    let string = letter;
    if (vowels.includes(letter) && vowels.includes(wordArr[index + 1])) {
      string += '-'
    }

    return `${sentence}${string}`;
  }, '');
}

console.log(insertDash("Thiis is a teest"));
```